# Detect if the context menu is currently open/active with AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript, mouse

I'm using some software to customize my mouse behavior and it is able to run AppleScripts as part of it's functionality. I'd like to make it so when I right click and hold to open the context menu on something, I can use my scroll wheel to scroll to scroll through the items and the release to select one. For this I need to be able to detect whether or not the context menu is open in order to change the behavior of the scroll wheel appropriately. Any advice on how to do this?

Comment: What software?  What method are you currently using to open the context menu?

Comment: It’s called controllermate. Im just opening it with right click or CTRL+click like you normally would on a Mac. The problem is that just because I right clicked doesn’t mean there is actually a context menu open. I need to detect when there is an active context menu.

Comment: The difficulty in this is that a context menu is a child object of the `UI Element` you right-click on, and not simply a first-order element that belongs to the frontmost `application process`. So to test for its existence, you have to recurse through the UI object hierarchy until either you find it, or you run out of  elements (in which case it doesn't exist).  _Cont'd..._

Comment: _...Cont'd_ This is doable; I just wrote a script that does it, with three concerns: ① time taken increases with depth of hierarchy; ② worst case scenario is when the menu _doesn't_ exist; ③ it won't operate on apps that don't expose the right UI accessibility information, which means any web browser and probably any electronJS app aren't possible to apply this method to. _Cont'd..._

Comment: _...Cont'd_ I, personally, don't know of another way to test for the menu's existence.  So that leaves me to ask what the negative effects would be of having your macro or workflow (or whatever _ControllerMate_ calls it) proceed to perform the actions you describe even when a context menu does not exist ?  Knowing that might present other attack points that could engineer a solution by mitigating the negative effects or preventing them from occurring. ◾️